# How do I count words with apostrophe character

Tags: c, count, cs50, cpu-word

I am working on a word count program in C.
Everything works fine but When I came to apostrophe character control, I was a little bit confused.
The issue is, that my program is not able to recognize the difference between these two examples:  I've and Jem's.
My program counts it as two words if there is an apostrophe character in the word. It is supposed to count the first example as 2 words, and the second example as one word.
Do you have any idea what's wrong, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    string inputstr;
    int letters = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int sentences = 0;
    char c;
    float index;

    inputstr = get_string("Text:");

    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(inputstr); i++)
    {
        c = inputstr[i];

        if (isalnum(c))//count letters
        {
            letters++;

        }
        else if (isspace(c) || c == '\0' || c == 39)//count words
        {
            words++;

        }
        else if (c == '.' || c == '?' || c == '!')//count sentences
        {
            sentences++;

        }

    }//end of for loop

    return 0;
}// end of main
```

Comment: It's pretty tricky to do accurately. You'll probably have to drastically increase the complexity of your algorithm.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible without really understanding the words and what kind of elision the apostrophe marks. How will your program know whether "Jem's" means "Jem is" or "belonging to Jem"? Does your program even know that the words are in English?

Comment: You could do something like analyzing whatever comes between the apostrophe and the next separator. If it is "ve" then treat it as a word. But making it understand the difference between  "Jem is" and "belonging to Jem" is very hard. You could basically make a master thesis on that particular subject.

Comment: You'll need a rather compilcated finite state machine + some heuristics. (or a look-up table for the allowed fragments after the apostrophe) Another way is to always consider the constructs as three separate tokens by the tokeniser, and *maybe* merge the tokens in second (*semantic*) step.

Comment: It is uncommon in written text for "Jem's" to mean "Jem is". It is informal and so it is usually seen in *reported speech*. For the purpose of the exercise I would treat all words that end in apostrophe-s as a single word.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: A minimal state machine would need about five states. It is not that hard to get it *almost* right. But it is impossible to get it **always** right.

Comment: Don't forget that `Smiths'` is only one word.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick program that could give you some ideas. Please note that I hacked it together rather quickly. It's not very nicely written and may contain bugs. But it's enough to show the idea.

The basic idea is to look for an apostrophe in each word. If it finds one, look at what comes after the apostrophe and use that to decide if you should increment `count` or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *next(char *str, char *delims) {
    size_t len = strlen(delims);
    while(*str) {
        for(size_t i=0; i<len; i++)
            if(*str == delims[i]) return str+1;
        str++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "Now I've broken Johan's computer";
    char *delims = "., ";
    char *c = str;
    char *n;
    size_t count = 0;
    while(1) {
        n = next(c, delims);
        count++;
        ptrdiff_t d;
        if(!n) d = strlen(c);
        else d = n-c;
        char *word = malloc(d + 1);
        strncpy(word, c, d);
        printf("%zu %s\n", count, word);
        char *apo = next(word, "'");
        if(apo) {
            char *t = next(apo, delims);
            if(!t) d = strlen(apo);
            else d = t-apo;
            char *after = malloc(d+1);
            strncpy(after, apo, d-1);
            if(strcmp(after, "ve") == 0) count++;
            free(after);
        }
        free(word);
        if(!n) break;
        c = n;
    }
    printf("Count: %zu\n", count);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
1 Now 
2 I've 
4 broken 
5 Johan's 
6 computer
Count: 6
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. It was very helpful. I appreciate you. Checking the character that comes after apostrophe is the key point for me.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal finite state machine:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

        /* Tokenise, recognising word's AS a single token
        ** But NOT we're !111!!!
        */
int fetch_word(char *str, size_t len)
{
size_t pos;
int state;

state =0;
for (pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
        int ch;
        ch = str[pos];
        switch (state) {
        case 0: /* initial or whitespace */
                if (strspn(str+pos, " \t\r\n\v\f")) continue;
                if (pos) return -pos;
                if (isalpha(ch)) {state = 1; continue; }
                state = 4; continue;
        case 1: /* word */
                if (pos >= 2 && ch == '\'') {state = 2; continue; }
                if (isalpha(ch)) {continue; }
                return pos;
        case 2: /* word + apos */
                if (isalpha(ch)) {state = 3; continue; }
                return pos -1;
        case 3: /* word+ apos + letter */
                if (strspn(str+pos, " \t\r\n\v\f")) return pos;
                return pos -2;
        case 4: /* other */
                if (isalpha(ch)) return -pos;
                if (!strspn(str+pos, " \t\r\n\v\f")) continue;
                return -pos;
                break;
                }
        }
/* not reached (well:seldom) */
return (state==1) ? pos : -pos;
}

int main(void)
{
char buff[200];
int ret;
size_t pos,len,count;

count=0;
while ( fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin) ) {
        len = strlen(buff);
        for(pos= 0; pos < len ; pos += ret) {
                ret = fetch_word(buff+pos, len-pos);
                if (!ret) break;
                if (ret < 0) { ret = -ret; continue; }
                printf("%zu+%d:%.*s\n" , pos, ret, ret, buff+pos);
                count++;
                }
        }
printf(" Count=%zu\n" , count);
return 0;
}
```

---

Feed it its own source file:

---

```
1+7:include
10+5:stdio
16+1:h
1+7:include
10+6:string
17+1:h
1+7:include
10+5:ctype
16+1:h
4+8:Tokenise
14+11:recognising
26+6:word's
33+2:AS
36+1:a
38+6:single
45+5:token
4+3:But
8+3:NOT
12+2:we
15+2:re
0+3:int
4+5:fetch
```

**rest snipped**